# how to define execution sequence in angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, model-view-controller, firebase

I am trying to display google map and markers. and it went well. Now I tried to call a method which will dynamically set the center of map's latitude and longitude, but the center is undefined as the error says, because the map is drawn before the function returns (or sets) the centered latitude and longitude of map.  and thus giving us the undefined error. How to execute the coords() function completely, before the map is drawn. 
On the other hand. I counter checked the cause,by hard coding latitude and the map is then drawn well.    I have even tried callback but could not achieve desired results.

below is my controller code (js) and view (html).

```js
var appa = angular.module('appa',['firebase','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
appa.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebaseObject,$scope) {

              $scope.coords = function(){
                var ref =  firebase.database().ref();
                var latArray = [];
                var lngArray = [];
                var cenlat;
                var cenlng;
                  var marker = [];
                ref.once("value")
                .then(function(snapshot)
                {
                snapshot.forEach(function(child)
                {

                  latArray.push(child.child("Lat").val());
                  console.log(child.child("Lat").val());
                  lngArray.push(child.child("Long").val());
                  var mark = {
                  id: child.child("Id").val(),
                  coords: {
                  latitude: child.child("Lat").val(),
                  longitude: child.child("Long").val()
                  },
                  options: { title: child.child("Alt").val() }
                  };
                  marker.push(mark);
                });

                   cenlat = (Math.max.apply(Math,latArray)+Math.min.apply(Math,latArray)/2);
                   cenlng = (Math.max.apply(Math,lngArray)+Math.min.apply(Math,lngArray)/2);

                });
                $scope.map.center.latitude = cenlat;
                $scope.map.center.longitude = cenlng;
                };

              $scope.map = {
                center:
                {
                  latitude: 51,
                  longitude: 4
                         },
                 zoom: 2
                      };

                $scope.coords();

   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org/" >

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDF-sQ_g7FJ46HeYo8e4dpVukyDkdE5UXw"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            position: relative;
        }

        .angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="appa">
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
      <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in marker" coords="m.coords" options="m.options" idkey="m.id">
           </ui-gmap-marker>
                    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
<!--example-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to remove the hard coded `$scope.map.center`, create it in the `$scope.coords` function and then add `ng-if` to the HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" ng-if="map.center">
```

Now the directive will not render until `$scope.map.center` exists, which will be when the asynchronous `$scope.coords` has completed.